# Frame swapping is not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to switch the frame, but not able to do it

1st Page(frame) should have red background color and "Hello" button and Frame size should have 900x650 as window size. When press "Hello" button it should swap to 2nd frame

2nd page (frame) should have green background color and "Hello" button and Frame size should have 900x650 as window size.  When press "Hello" button it should swap to 1st frame

```
import Tkinter as tk

def raise_frame(frame):
    print "Inside raise frame"
    frame.tkraise()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x650+220+20")
root.title("Testing")


frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=900, height=650, background="red")
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, width=900, height=650, background="green")


B1= tk.Button(frame1, text="Hello", width =10, height=2, command = lambda:raise_frame(frame2)).place (x=200, y=200)
B2= tk.Button(frame2, text="Hello", width =10, height=2, command = lambda:raise_frame(frame1)).place (x=400, y=400)



frame1.pack( )
frame2.pack( )

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `pack()`, the second frame is placed **below** the first frame. You can check that by dragging the bottom part of the window. You'll see that there are 2 frames created with the red on the top, and the green on the bottom.

You can use [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) to place the frames on top of each other.

So, replace the lines

```
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()
```

with

```
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: @ Keyur Potdar Excellent answer. May i know how grid is differ from pack.

Comment: am getting green background(2nd page) at first instead of 1st page

Comment: Change the order of grid. ie, frame2 first, and the frame1. The last item you add in the grid, is the one you see on the top.

Comment: Thank you, changing the order of grid didn't give any effect, But i changed frame declare order like below `frame2 = tk.Frame(root, width=900, height=650, background="green") frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=900, height=650, background="red")`code`

Comment: @velpandian Pack fills a 'cavity' dynamically whereas grid always places the widget on a node, be nodes bigger or smaller.